# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Here is the issue i am running in:

I have installed using anaconda and later with pip: `conda install -c conda-forge bottle`

When i run my code in spyder:

```
from bottle import run, post


@post('/')  
def main():  
    return 


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I get this:

```
Bottle v0.12.18 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But when i try to run `python bot.py` in command i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bottle import run, post
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bottle'
```

Why is it showing me this error since `bottle` is clearly installed?

Comment: I think you need `python3 bot.py`

Comment: I just tried that but still got the same error

Comment: Did you create a new environment in `conda`? Try `conda activate base && python bot.py`

Comment: i was trying to run it on cmd not conda, but yes i was able to run it on conda. Any idea as to why it was not working in cmd?

Comment: You can make it work on `cmd`, just need to activate `conda` environment so that the path towards your Python interpreter is updated to the correct one with the installed package `bot`.

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion. Conda is using a virtual environment. The packages are installed in the virtualenv. If you run it without conda you are not using the virtualenv so you have to manually select it like @Arnaud is proposing. https://towardsdatascience.com/virtual-environments-104c62d48c54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing pip first and then running the command

```
pip install bottle
```

in your shell.